# Joomla/Virtuemart help needed

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Running
Joomla 1.5.21 & Virtuemart1.1.5

This is what I have done so far....

I copied an existing website that was running Joomla & Virtuemart, scripted out & created (with all the existing data) the MySql tables, changing the prefix of the tables & updated the Joomla configuration file to point to the new db (changing the username/password & table prefix).  But now I when I login to the back end & update a virtuemart item, the site I copied  this site from gets updated.

So my question is, where in virtuemart are the database settings??

AHIA,
LarryR....

Comment: May I firstly suggest you update Joomla to the latest version (1.5.26). As for the item updating in VirtueMart, you said you updated the database username and password, but did you change the actual database name?

Comment: Lodder...yes, I did change the database name in the configuration file.

Comment: If you have changed the database name, username and password in phpMyAdmin AND the configuration.php file then I dont see how this is happening as it should be connecting to the new database.

Comment: I created a new user for this new site & updated configuration.php to reflect the same (user/pass/db).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In    `administrator/com_virtuemart/virtuemart.cfg.php` change your SITEURL